# New ubuntu 14.04.1 updates broke ssl components

Tags: server, apache2, ssl

Yesterday night I did `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` and after all the updates to Ubuntu 14.04.1 and apache 2.4, ssl stopped working.

Its an apache server running multiple sites and I have created a host file for each website. All the http sites on the server are working. A couple of websites that are https and have 3rd party certs, which were working till the update, are now throwing ssl protocol errors. You can visit https://apps-sa.mcmaster.ca/enhance and have a look.

I looked through the logs and there is absolutely nothing I can find related to the error.

Answer (score 3):

`AllowOverride None` is now the default for Apache 2.4, so you need to explicitly allow overrides if you plan to use `.htaccess` files. If you intend to use `mod_rewrite` or other settings in `.htaccess` files, you can allow which directives declared in that file can override server configuration. After the updates, `AllowOverride None` was added to my `apache2.conf` file which I completely ignored. Once I hashed out all the directives in `apache2.conf`, the sites were back up.